# Bitrise Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo

Tags: android, bitrise

I have created a class with the Espresso Test, named InsertFirst.class, I have correctly tried it on my android studio project, and it works.
Now I am trying to do the same on Bitrise. I have this worflow:

1. Activate SSH key (RSA private key)
2. Git Clone Repository
3. Bitrise.io Cache:Pull
4. Do anything with Script step
5. Install missing Android SDK components
6. Android Lint
7. Android Unit Test
8. Android Build for UI Testing
9. [BETA] Virtual Device Testing for Android
10. Android Build
11. Deploy to Bitrise.io - Apps, Logs, Artifacts
12. Bitrise.io Cache:Push

All the steps works, a part of the step 9. That I have configured in this way:
[image: Step Configuration]

But when I run a build I get this ouptup on this step:

```
Configs:
- AppPath: /bitrise/deploy/app-debug.apk
- TestTimeout: 900.000000
- FlakyTestAttempts: 0
- DownloadTestResults: false
- DirectoriesToPull: 
- AutoGoogleLogin: false
- EnvironmentVariables: 
- ObbFilesList: 
- TestDevices:
---
Model    API Level   Locale   Orientation   
Nexus6   24          en       portrait      
---
- TestType: instrumentation
- TestApkPath: /bitrise/deploy/app-debug-androidTest.apk
- InstTestPackageID: 
- InstTestRunnerClass: com.app.name.nameeapp.ui.login.InsertFirst
- InstTestTargets: 
- UseOrchestrator: false
Uploading app and test files
- (1/1) running
- (0/1) running
=> Test finished
Test results:
Model    API Level   Locale   Orientation   Outcome              
Nexus6   24          en       portrait      failure
```

And If I go to the Test Report, on the Firebase TestLab -> Test Artifacts -> instrumentation.results
I got this error:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.app.name.nameeapp.test/com.app.name.nameeapp.ui.login.InsertFirst}
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: com.app.cerere.cerereapp.test/com.app.name.nameeapp.ui.login.InsertFirst
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:890)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:400)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:121)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:262)
```

Why? I miss something in the step? Or there is something that I forgot? Thanks

Comment: I would see if you can upload these APKs onto Firebase Test Lab through the Firebase Console and run the tests there to make sure they pass before trying the whole CI/CD.

Comment: Also, I had an issue when I first tried this because the device I choose was smaller than what I designed for.